# Java advanced mail library

Tags: java, email

I want to create an app which integrate my POP3 mail which is hosted at ISP and on college server, access to servers is through 2 different proxies and this is problem because JavaMail only use proxy from preferences.

I need java mail library which allow connections to POP3 servers via different proxies in same time.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I modified JavaMail source code :) and replaced socket creation **new Socket()** with **new Socket(proxy)** - work well, no problems

Comment: Can you share your modified library?